# SKMaps - App Errors Uploading To iTunes Connect - Invalid Binary - Segment Alignment - Encryption

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, skmaps

I am trying to upload my app with SKMaps.framework to the App Store. App runs perfect on simulator and device.

But I get the below errors uploading build to iTunes Connect.

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for
>   "xxxx xxxx". To process your delivery, the following issues must be
>   corrected:
>
> **Invalid Binary Architecture** - iOS 3.0 introduced support for multiple
>   binary architectures. If your binary is built for multiple
>   architectures, your Info.plist must have a MinimumOSVersion key with a
>   value of at least 3.0. Additionally, if your app is intended to
>   support earlier iPhone and iPod touch models, your app must contain at
>   least an armv6 binary; "thin" armv7-only binaries will not be accepted
>   unless the armv7 required device capability is also present in the
>   Info.plist UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key or the MinimumOSVersion
>   key has a value of 4.3 or higher.
>
> Specifically, we found the following unsupported architectures in your
>   binary:
>
> x86_64 i386 For more information, see Technical Q&A QA1707 at:
>   http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2010/qa1707.html.
>
> **Invalid Segment Alignment** - The app binary at 'xxxx
>   xxxx.app/Frameworks/SKMaps.framework/SKMaps' does not have proper
>   segment alignment. Try rebuilding the app with the latest Xcode
>   version.
>
> Invalid Encryption Info - The binary is invalid. The encryption info
>   in the LC_ENCRYPTION_INFO load command is either missing or invalid,
>   or the binary is already encrypted. This binary does not seem to have
>   been built with Apple's linker.
>
> Though you are not required to fix the following issues, we wanted to
>   make you aware of them:
>
> **Non-PIE Binary** - The executable 'Payload/xxxx
>   xxxx.app/Frameworks/SKMaps.framework' is not a Position Independent
>   Executable. Please ensure that your build settings are configured to
>   create PIE executables. For more information, refer to Technical Q&A
>   QA1788 - Building a Position Independent Executable
>
> Once the required corrections have been made, you can then redeliver
>   the corrected binary.
>
> Regards,
>
> The App Store team

Without this framework, my app is totally useless. The framework version is 3.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the build without the simulator slice, this should solve you problem. You can find the latest build here: http://forum.skobbler.com/showthread.php/14602-3-0-3-release-candidate-builds?p=32322